# Move jboss install from one redhat box to another

Tags: reinstall, redhat-enterprise-linux, jboss

I have an old jboss installation running on an old RHEL box that I would like to move to another upgraded RHEL, joss version is 3.2.3.

Would it be sufficient to move the jboss directory or does it store any config files anywhere else?

Comment: From what I know, the configuration files are inside the folders under the main "server" folder. I mean, "default" or any other folder that you could have. So, if you move the folders, you are moving all the information related to the deployed applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine, if you move the entire Jboss folder. Please check your startup script and ensure that none of the config files are outside the Jboss folder.

Running (ps -ef | grep -i jboss) will show you the command line options being used to start Jboss and it should also show you the config file being specified.

And finally, make sure you have a compatible Java version installed on the new server.